# If first option is selected prepend text

Tags: jquery

I have a different variety of options from which you can choose. When the first option is chosen, a text should prepend another div. If the first option is NOT chosen, the text should disappear.

I was thinking working with a toggleClass or addClass or removeClass should do the trick but couldn't quite manage to fix my problem.

My code looks like this:

```
<div id="WA_price">
    <p class="WA_price2">200&nbsp;€</p>
</div>

 <div class="input-box">
        <select name="super_attribute[149]" id="attribute149" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
            <option value="0">Choose option…</option>
            <option value="28" price="139" data-label="1000 mm">1000 mm</option>
            <option value="30" price="169" data-label="1200 mm" class="selected">1200 mm</option>
            <option value="32" price="199" data-label="1400 mm">1400 mm</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
jQuery('<span class="preis_ab">ab </span>').insertBefore('.WA_price2');
jQuery( "option" ).each(function() {
      if ('jQuery("option:first-child").hasClass("selected")') {
        jQuery('.preis_ab').addClass('show');
        } else if ('jQuery("option:not(:first-child)").hasClass("selected")') {
            jQuery('.preis_ab').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind an event handler to your select element. Using `.on()` you can detect a `change` in the select element (using its id in this case). From there, you can hide and show the div based on the value that is currently selected (this value is retrieved from your html `value` attribute on each option.

```js
$('<span class="preis_ab">ab </span>').insertBefore('.WA_price2').hide();

$("#attribute149").on('change', function(){
  if ($(this).val() === "28") $('.preis_ab').show();
  else $('.preis_ab').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="WA_price">
    <p class="WA_price2">200&nbsp;€</p>
</div>

 <div class="input-box">
        <select name="super_attribute[149]" id="attribute149" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
            <option value="0">Choose option…</option>
            <option value="28" price="139" data-label="1000 mm">1000 mm</option>
            <option value="30" price="169" data-label="1200 mm" class="selected">1200 mm</option>
            <option value="32" price="199" data-label="1400 mm">1400 mm</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: works perfect, just changed the if ($(this).val() === "28") $('.preis_ab').show(); into  if (jQuery("option:first-child").hasClass("selected")) jQuery('.preis_ab').show();

Comment: but do you have any idea why prepend doesnt work instead of insertBefore

Comment: ah no i figured it out if I prepend the span into the .WA_price2 this div gets the .hide() and not the span

Answer (score 0):

use [.change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) on the select to show and hide the div...

```js
jQuery('<span class="preis_ab">ab </span>').insertBefore('.WA_price2');

  $( ".super-attribute-select" ).change(function () {
   
    $( ".super-attribute-select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      if($( this ).val()=='28') $('.preis_ab').show();
      else $('.preis_ab').hide();
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="WA_price">
    <p class="WA_price2">200&nbsp;€</p>
</div>

 <div class="input-box">
        <select name="super_attribute[149]" id="attribute149" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
            <option value="0">Choose option…</option>
            <option value="28" price="139" data-label="1000 mm">1000 mm</option>
            <option value="30" price="169" data-label="1200 mm" class="selected">1200 mm</option>
            <option value="32" price="199" data-label="1400 mm">1400 mm</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the span element at [dom ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) and [hide](https://api.jquery.com/hide/). When a [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event happens you can [toggle the visibility](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) of the span based on the selected [index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex):

```js
jQuery(function () {
    //
   // add span and hide
   //
    jQuery('<span class="preis_ab">ab </span>').insertBefore('.WA_price2').hide();
    jQuery('#attribute149').on('change', function(e) {
         //
         // toggle visibility if the index of selected option is 1
         //
        jQuery('#WA_price .preis_ab').toggle(this.selectedIndex == 1);
        
        //
        // a different approach is: check if option with
        // value 28 is selected
        //
        //jQuery('#WA_price .preis_ab').toggle(
        //   jQuery('#attribute149 option[value=28]').is(':selected'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="WA_price">
    <p class="WA_price2">200&nbsp;€</p>
</div>

<div class="input-box">
    <select name="super_attribute[149]" id="attribute149" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
        <option value="0">Choose option…</option>
        <option value="28" price="139" data-label="1000 mm">1000 mm</option>
        <option value="30" price="169" data-label="1200 mm" class="selected">1200 mm</option>
        <option value="32" price="199" data-label="1400 mm">1400 mm</option>
    </select>
</div>
```